# Returning a smart pointer and assign it a value doesn't work

Tags: c++

I am having some problems modifying the content of a smart pointer returned by a class function. Returning a reference to the pointer would be a solution, but I am concerned of it as a bad practice.

This is my code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : ptr_(new int(5)) {};
    ~Foo() {};

    std::shared_ptr<int> bar()
    {
        return ptr_;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << *ptr_ << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.print();

    // First case
    f.bar() = std::make_shared<int>(23);
    f.print();

    // Second case
    f.bar().reset(new int(23));
    f.print();

    // Third case
    *f.bar() = 23;
    f.print();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
5
5
5
23
```

Why only in the third case ptr_ changes its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**bar()** returns a copy of the `shared_ptr`.
So assigning to that copy doesn't change the original `shared_ptr`.

To make it work as you expected, you should have returned a reference to the internal pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<int>& bar()
{
   return ptr_;
}
```

Comment: But I always thought that a pointer points to a memory address. If I am returning a pointer that points to the same memory address every time, why isn't the value changing?

Comment: @Puyover You are returning a copy. In your case, because you haven't declared a variable, a new temporary variable is created. You are doing and assignment to that new variable, which means it now points at something else. But it's not the same variable that exists in the object.

Comment: @Puyover You're not returning a *pointer*, you're returning a *smart pointer* with is an object containing a pointer.

Comment: @OP Because shared_ptr is wrapper for an owning pointer. It is not actually a pointer, but it is a class, which you have made objects of. It contains a pointer, but it is not one.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. The syntax of not creating a variable to store the returned pointer was messing me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first two cases you only change the returned *copy*. In the third case you change what the pointer actually points to.

If you want the first two cases to work, return a reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `bar()` should return a reference to the shared pointer in order to do what you expect :

```
 std::shared_ptr<int>& bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the first two cases are using the assignment operator on a temp returned by bar(), effectively splitting it off from Foo.  In the last case, the dereference allows direct mutation on the shared payload.